# Launch the same screen flow from different buttons

Tags: quickaction, screen-flow, lightning-record-page

I need to create **three buttons** On Custom Object Record Page which will have similar logic for sending emails.
(Only difference in  to who this email will be sent).
I want to use Quick Action and Screen Flow for this.
However I do not want to create **three Screen Flows**, **just one**.

**Is there a way to check from *Screen Flow* from whic button it was launched ??**

I can not find anything when creating New Quick Action or in Flow Builder

[image]

*Maybe someone has already done something similar ?*

*Any help will be appreciated.

thank you*

Comment: Alternative: Use [Custom Buttons w/ Flow URL params](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url_variable.htm&type=5)

Comment: @cropredy Thanks, it is excatly what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option:

Instead of using Quick Actions, use Custom Buttons of Type URL

- Every screen flow has a URL that you can find in the Flow dropdown `View Details and Versions`
- Add input variables to your Screen Flow, in your case, call it something like `launchedFromButton` (Text variable)
- On each custom Button, add the URL parameter `launchedFromButton=MyButtonX`
- Be sure to include a `recordId` Flow input variable and include that in the custom button URL as well
- Remember that Flow variables are case sensitive when used for input/output

An example of this can be found in the Help [Distribute Flows with URL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url_variable.htm&type=5)

> `/flow/Contact_Info?collNames={!Contact.FirstName}&collNames={!Contact.LastName}`

> `/flow/User_Info?varUserFirst={!$User.FirstName}&varUserLast={!$User.LastName}`

> ...

Comment: thank you......